# async-await threading internals

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm curious about async await threading internals.

Everyone states that async is so much better in case of performance, because it frees threads that are waiting for a response to a long asynchronous call.
Ok I get it.

But let's consider this scenario.

I have an async methodA executing an async operation on database.
The api of the database exposes function BeginQuery and event QueryCompleted.
I wrapped those with a task (with use of TaskCompletionSource).

My question is what is going under the hood between calling BeginQuery and firing event QueryCompleted.

I mean - doesn't it need to spawn some kind of worker to fire the event? At the very low level it must be some synchronous loop that is blocking a thread reading result from db.

What I suppose is that any async call must generate a thread to actually handle the response (maybe wait for it in a low level c++ loop in driver code).

So our only "gain" is that the caller thread can be freed when some other thread is doing its work.

Does calling an asynchronous method always create a new worker thread?

Could someone confirm my understanding?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that "Everyone states that async is so much better in case of performance". Async/await can make applications more responsive because it makes it easier to use tasks and continuations for the user interface.

Comment: Async/await is a higher level abstraction than threads. The operations are synchronized on a SynchronizationContext, and the implementation of the engine that does that may or may not involve creating additional threads. See e.g. [It's All About the SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Everyone states that async is so much better in case of performance, because it frees threads that are waiting for a response to a long asynchronous call.

Yes and no. The point behind `async` is to free up the calling thread. In UI applications, the primary benefit of `async` is responsiveness, because the UI thread is freed up. In server applications, the primary benefit of `async` is scalability, because the request thread is freed up to handle other requests.

> So our only "gain" is that the caller thread can be freed when some other thread is doing its work.
>   Does always calling an asynchronous method is creating a new worker thread?

No. At the OS level, all I/O is asynchronous. It is the synchronous APIs which block a thread while the underlying asynchronous I/O is in progress. I recently wrote this up in a blog post: [there is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Together with the linked blog post it was very comprehensive lecture. I have a question though. If I would like to write a library that leverages asynchronous I/O, where do I start?
Do I need to write some unmanaged code? Can this be done purely in C#?

Comment: It can be done in purely managed code, but the instructions to do so are hard to find. [This is the best overview](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Using-Overlapped-IO-from-Managed-Code.aspx).

Comment: Bumping [There is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: I have been reading your article http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html. So as per my understanding, the request is sent to process to OS then to device driver and driver marked it as "pending" and sent it back to CPU and then returned to the program as incomplete task. But in background the device driver is actually running the operation. Once completed, sends an interrupt to CPU with response and follows some abstract path to program and program puts it into the queue. So the actual task is being performed on low level of OS while main thread is free?

Comment: @Vivek: No. With the disk example, then it's done by the disk hardware (not in the OS). The write is being performed by the HDD or HDD controller (off-CPU). The device driver just makes the request; it doesn't actually perform the write.

Answer (score 6):

> I mean - doesn't it need to spawn some kind of worker to fire the
>   event? At the very low level it must be some synchronous loop that is
>   blocking a thread reading result from db.

It will create an IO completion port (IOCP) representing a task that is being processed outside, and the thread will continue with other things. Then, when the IOCP notifies that the task is done, a thread will pick up the state of the IOCP and will continue the task.

http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/multithreaded-asynchronous-io-io-comple/201202921

> I/O completion ports provide an elegant solution to the problem of
>   writing scalable server applications that use multithreading and
>   asynchronous I/O.

Comment: This!  Using an IOCP is easier on the operating system than a full-blown thread.  Your OS can only handle a few thousand threads, but can handle a few million completion ports easily.  So with async/await, you limit the number of big heavy threads and use lighterweight OS objects called I/O completion ports that are easier to deal with.

Answer (score 5):

> I mean - doesn't it need to spawn some kind of worker to fire the
>   event? At the very low level it must be some synchronous loop that is
>   blocking a thread reading result from db.

Even when you actually have to wait for a kernel object (like a manual reset event), you still can turn a blocking synchronous code into asynchronous one and free the thread from blocking (updated: [a real-life scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21897055/1768303)).

For example, synchronous code:

```
void Consume()
{
    var completedMre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    producer.StartOperation(completedMre);

    completedMre.WaitOne(); // blocking wait

    Console.WriteLine(producer.DequeueResult());
}
```

Asynchronous analog:

```
async Task ConsumeAsync()
{
    var completedMre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    producer.StartOperation(completedMre);

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Result>();

    ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(completedMre, 
        (s, t) => tcs.SetResult(producer.DequeueResult()),
        null, Timeout.Infinite, true);

    var result = await tcs.Task;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

The asynchronous version scales for up to 64 times better (`MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`, that's the maximum number of kernel objects which can be aggregated by `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` for waiting on a single thread). So, you can call `Consume()` for 64 times in parallel and it will block 64 threads. Or you can call `ConsumeAsync` for 64 times and it will block just one thread.

Answer (score 1):

Async methods don't create new threads, they are based on `Task`s, which may or may not use threads (as with `TaskCompletionSource`), and even when they do there's no overhead because they use `ThreadPool`.