# C#: How do I wait for an event to be set?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to write a synchronous test that calls into some asynchronous product tasks.

In the example below, DoSomething() is called by a separate thread, and then it sets the SomethingCompleted event.

In my test code, how do I wait for SomethingCompleted to be set?

```
public event Action<Result> SomethingCompleted;

public void DoSomething()
{
    Something();

    this.SomethingCompleted(new Result("Success"));
}
```

Comment: Why not use `async` and `await` keyword ?

Comment: Do you really want to block a thread waiting on it? Or do you just want to do some stuff when the event fires?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21881615/1768303

Comment: Yes, I want to block the thread waiting on it. Like I said, I am writing test code against this product code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (var evt = new ManualResetEvent()) {
 Action<Result> handler = _ => evt.Set();
 SomethingCompleted += handler;
 evt.WaitOne();
 SomethingCompleted -= handler; //cut object reference to help GC
}
```

If required you can unsubscribe from the event after the wait has completed. That way the event will not keep the delegate and closure instance alive.

You can extract this into a reusable helper method/extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
// test case
public void Test() 
{

   var yourObj = new YourObj();
   var done = false;
   Result result;
   yourObj.SomethingCompleted += (finalResult) => {
     result=finalResult; 
     done=true;
   };

   yourObj.DoSomething();

   while(!done) Thread.Sleep(200);

   if(result != theExpectedResult) kaboom();
}
```

What about subscribing to an event and "polling" the lambda until result comes available? This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong type of event. The event you're using is a callback. In the code you supplied, the delegates attached to the `SomethingCompleted` event are going to be called on the same thread as `DoSomething`.

What you want is thread synchronization, using an event like [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) or [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx), which have nothing to do with the framework/language-level event that you're using. You could do something like this:

```
void MainThreadProc()
{
    // create thread synchronization event
    using (var evt = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        // start background operation
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(BackgroundThreadProc, evt);

        // this line will block until BackgroundThreadProc sets the event
        evt.WaitOne();
    }

    // resume main thread operations here
    ...
}

void BackgroundThreadProc(object o)
{
    // get event from argument
    var evt = (ManualResetEvent) o;

    // do the deed
    ...

    // set event to signal completion
    evt.Set();
}
```

This is just one of a number of different ways to do this. Alternatives include Parallel LINQ or the Task Parallel Library (both of which are best used with parallel operations, not just a single background operation). If you don't want to block the main thread, look at [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).