# Where and How Event watcher run in Async, Await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am going through Async programming and I understand that there is an
EventTable, Event Queue and Event loop.

In my understanding every-time compiler sees await in call-stack it registers an entry in Event Table. Whenever the result of async comes, entry from the event table is removed and put to Event queue.

let's say we are making an http call in async function. so I believe an entry will be made in Event Table and whenever response is returned from the http call particular code will be put in EventQueue to run. And Event loop will take care of running the code. But My question is who makes the http call and `who is tracking the response from the api` similarly in the case of `setTimeout() who is running the clock and checking the entires in Event Table`?

If some other process is keeping a track, that means on a single core machine 3 processes are running

1. event loop
2. actual function (whenever event loops pulls something out from event queue)
3. cron like job who keeps track of time, async response etc etc?

Extension of the above question is `what classifies to be run as async`.

Can we run `a = b + c` as async? (IMO, no since b+c will need to be calculated on machine only, hence does not make sense to do a = b + c in an async function)

If yes 
who will take care of calculating b + c?

If not what is the rule for a function to be truly async

Comment: What language does this question refer to? It is tagged `python-asyncio`, but then it mentions `setTimeout`, which doesn't exist in Python, and also of Event table and queue which are not standard Python asyncio concepts.

Comment: The question is for javascript but similar concepts exists in python as well. removing python from the tag list.

Comment: They do indeed, but the details differ quite a bit, so the question doesn't even fully make sense for Python, and the Python answers might not apply to JavaScript. You might want to add a JavaScript tag as well, to attract experts from that part of SO. Good luck!

Comment: Operating system exposes the event loop, so you don't poll manually for updates. `v8`, in case of JavaScript (Chrome), takes care of the event loop. Event loop uses multiple threads, but there's one thread that you, programmer, get to play with. The others are so that callbacks can be executed and results returned to the main thread. The only thing that can be classified as async is when you have two units of computing that run at different paces, under different logical circuits sort-to-speak. Use case is to allow CPU to do other things while network/hdd (slow parts) are doing their own thing

Comment: Yes, the http call or timeout runs somewhere in the background - either on a separate thread, or handled by the operating system itself in an asynchronous manner. "*what classifies to be run as async*" - only native code can put entries in the event table, it needs to expose that as an API (such as `setTimeout` or `fetch`) to javascript. You can't start a thread for that addition from js.

Comment: thanks @Bergi in the case of single core machine what does it mean? will setTimeout and fetch also have some overhead?

Comment: @hello123 Single core doesn't mean no multi-threading on any standard OS.

Comment: I meant that the resources would be shared right?

Comment: @Bergi an interesting thing i read, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/21880086/3892213 and http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html and https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12341909 They say that in the case of window io operations are async but in the case of linux io operations are sync and 1 thread has to keep polling it. Would it not mean passing my synchronous task to a lower level task?